# XSendFile Apache2 mod has zero bytes

Tags: php, apache, x-sendfile

My code, the paths are correct and the content length is correct

```
header("X-Sendfile: " . $savePath); 
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($savePath));
header("Content-type: $type");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($localFilename) . '"');

exit();
```

My .htaccess

```
<Files file.php>
    XSendFile on
</Files>
```

This always results in a zero sized file download.

The file is definitely there and in the right place. Using  `curl -I` shows me the following which appears to be fine. But the file is still zero bytes.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 21 Feb 2015 11:35:37 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.29 (Amazon)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.29
X-Sendfile: /var/www/html/cache/72b08eb707bb5eab58d8e5d7d9b21bb8.jpeg
Content-Length: 10004
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="72b08eb707bb5eab58d8e5d7d9b21bb8.jpeg"
Connection: close
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3):

So it turns out that you need to use

```
XSendFile on
```

In your main Apache2 conf otherwise it will not work anywhere